# How to fix Text widget padding?

Tags: flutter, dart

As the font size increases, indents are added below and above inside the widget, because of which the elements are at different levels. How to remove this indent? Screen on the link

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
       child: Row(
         mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
         crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
         children: <Widget>[
            Text("24°"),
            Text("40°", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 80.0,), textAlign: TextAlign.end),
            Text("42°")
         ],
       ),
    );
  }
```

[Widget screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQd8y.png)

Answer (score 1):

This solution reduces the **weird shift** problem.

```
Container(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.baseline,
          textBaseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              "24°",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40.0),
            ),
            Text(
              "40°",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 100.0),
            ),
            Text(
              "42°",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40.0),
            )
          ],
        ),
      )
```

[image: output]

**EDIT**:

[image: showing the baseline]

Comment: Thanks! But this does not solve the problem, but I’ll leave it and I will take this indent into account

Comment: @ДмитрийГригорьев I think that is as much as you can do in this situation, Do update if you find the solution

Comment: you can see the all text is aligned to baseline but now common padding appears below each text.